# Unable to install Truffle - Warn and Error

Tags: truffle, npm

I am trying to install Truffle with Windows 10, but I had problem when run npm install -g truffle. PowerShell always appear Warn and Error, I've installed Node.Js and VS Code. This is my error :

```
PS C:\Users\Tri Mega W> npm install -g truffle
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated ipld-raw@6.0.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated cids@1.1.9: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated ipld-dag-cbor@0.17.1: This module has been superseded by @ipld/dag-cbor and multiformats
npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated @nodefactory/filsnap-adapter@0.2.2: Package is deprecated in favour of @chainsafe/filsnap-adapter
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@3.1.2: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated ipld-dag-pb@0.20.0: This module has been superseded by @ipld/dag-pb and multiformats
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@3.2.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.20.0: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\@trufflesuite\bigint-buffer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.2 found at "C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Tri Mega W\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\@trufflesuite\bigint-buffer
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tri Mega W\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-04T02_30_18_482Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

had this same problem, but when I tried to run the windows-build-tools, it just gost stucked.
Tried a few times and instead of trying to do the installation via Chocolatey, I just ignored it (since it showed me that python 2.7 was installed anyway). And it finally worked! Thank you!

Also, if you get a warning about scripts after checking for truffle version, follow the link in the message about Execution Polices and run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

then try `truffle version` and it should work!

Comment: I have tried & it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The node-gyp docs state that "node-gyp requires that you have installed a compatible version of Python, one of: v3.6, v3.7, v3.8, or v3.9.", and you seem to have 3.8, so we can hope thats not the problem

Do not worry about the warnings. For the errors, try this:

- Run `npm install --global windows-build-tools`
- Install node-gyp: `npm install -g node-gyp`
- Clear npm cache: `npm cache clear --force`
- Finally hit `npm i -g truffle`

Hope it helps!

By the way, Im running Windows 10, with Node 16.14.0 and npm 8.3.1

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with nodeJS v17 and v18 now.
Try v14 or v16. I still get warning messages, but it works.